# Adding a repository throws bean creation error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, repository

My app was working fine until I tried adding a second repository. The stack trace mentions a requestMappingHandlerAdapter, that I can't find in my code. Any idea what this is trying to tell me? This is my first Java Project starting from the ground up so I am not sure if it is my security or configuration, or just something wrong with my new repository.  Thanks for any help!

Here's the stack trace with the error(s):

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.project1.models.Broker
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at com.project1.TangramPortalApplication.main(TangramPortalApplication.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.project1.models.Broker
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.project1.models.Broker
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:394) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:366) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7cdfcce8.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:602) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:536) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:564) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:479) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7cdfcce8.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$7(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7cdfcce8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$89a8c53f.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7cdfcce8.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.project1.models.Broker
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.project1.models.Broker
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.<init>(Repositories.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter.setApplicationContext(DomainClassConverter.java:109) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration.addFormatters(SpringDataWebConfiguration.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addFormatters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addFormatters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:78) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.mvcConversionService(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:507) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7cdfcce8.CGLIB$mvcConversionService$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7cdfcce8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$89a8c53f.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7cdfcce8.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.project1.models.Broker
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:552) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:188) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:139) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:123) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:64) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 72 common frames omitted
```

My BrokerRepository.java:

```html
import com.project1.models.Broker;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface BrokerRepository extends CrudRepository<Broker,Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

    Broker save(Broker entity);

    <Optional>Broker findById(Long id);

    void delete(Broker entity);

    List<Broker> findAll();

}
```

my POM.XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.project</groupId>
 <artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <name>Project1</name>
 <description>Project1</description>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.dblock.waffle</groupId>
   <artifactId>waffle-spring-security3</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security.kerberos</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-kerberos-web</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- flying saucer pdf -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
   <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
   <version>9.1.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- jxls simple excel -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
   <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
   <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.14</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
   <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!--<dependency>-->
  <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
  <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
  <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
  <!--</dependency>-->
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Does your `Broker` have @Entity annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual error is `Not a managed type: class com.project1.models.Broker`

This mean that `Broker` is not managed by spring. So you should add `@Entity` annotation to `Broker`.

And if it will not help - add `@EntityScan( basePackages = {"com.project1.models"} )` to your start application class